# Data is not changed after editing sqlitedatabase in android

Tags: android

i am working on an android project where i want to list the data from my existing `sqlite` database (`TEST.sqlite`) into my android `Listview.i` achieved this but my problem is that my `listview` is not getting updated when i changes the datas in my sqlite database.my `listview` is remained with the datas when i first created the `sqlite` database.how to change the values of my `listview` when i modify the database?can anyone find me a solution regarding this??

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;
ListView lvUsers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        dbHeplper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvUsers); 
ArrayList<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();

listUsers = (ArrayList<String>) dbHeplper.getAllUsers();

    if(listUsers != null){
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                listUsers);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**databasehelper class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.databaseandlist2/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "Test.sqlite";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TB_USER = "Users";
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private Context context;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);    
    this.context = context;
}
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDB!=null){
        myDB.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();        

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getAllUsers(){
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
        if(c == null) return null;

        String name;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {            
            name = c.getString(1);            
            listUsers.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();        

    return listUsers;
}
}
```

Comment: where ur inserting records?

Comment: i'm using my existing database i just copied it in my assets folder.i'm inserting datas in my existing database table.

Comment: hey when you make changes in database and after that you should also have to update your adapter and that set updated adapter to your listview than it will show you latest values of database.

Comment: how did you update date in sqlite database ?

Comment: are you inserting data into your db and adding the db to the asset?is that data is what not being shown?

Comment: yes i'm inserting data into my db .

Comment: Show ur inserting code

Comment: no i'm inserting it manualy in my sqlite database.

Comment: if u inserting records by coding then u can use the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` otherwise no use of it

Answer (score 0):

Declare this Globally `List<String> listUsers`
Use `ArrayAdapter` instead of `ListAdapter`
Whenever you insert new records or update your database you need to call again

```
listUsers = dbHeplper.getAllUsers();
```

and after that you just Notify Changes with

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter it is showing me error.

Comment: Try using `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: you need to use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` where you are inserting new record in db

Comment: buddy where is ur insert record code? how ur inserting records? please read my answer and check what i written

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65666/discussion-between-thushara-prasad-and-w-i-z-a-r-d).

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you change something in your DB, like put it inside the `onClick` when the user press the `insert` `button`.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please leave a comment when downvoting my answer